# How can I remove this unwanted gray area of my custom navigation bar when a navigation item is added?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I made a custom `UINavigationBar` class that works well except when I put `UINavigationItem` using `setItems([navitems],animated; true)`. Then this strange gray area appears (background of the nav bar). Is there any way I can get rid of this small section at the bottom or make the color uniform?

See image here for what is being displayed:

[image: Navigation bar with unwanted gray area]

Custom Nav class:

```
class navBar: UINavigationBar{

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        self.layer.cornerRadius=25;
        self.clipsToBounds = true;
    }



    func setupseg(controller: ViewController){
        let camera = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.organize, target: controller, action: #selector(controller.mapOption))

        let navitem = UINavigationItem()
        navitem.setRightBarButton(camera, animated: false)
        self.setItems([navitem], animated: true)

    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Comment: you are setting the color gray ?  self.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray in your init method

Comment: where you are setting this navbar to navigationController ? or using just navBar in view ?

Comment: Change 'self.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray' to 'self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear'

Comment: Hey jawad, I am just using a subclass of UInavigationBar. Still have no idea what is causing this footer area. Is it because all UINavbars have a fixed height?